# how to get a dynamically created graph in highchart using json data

Tags: java, javascript, json, highcharts

I want a dynamically generated graph in high chart using json data

Manually the graph is plotted like this

```
$(function () { 
    var i=7.0;
    $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Search Relevancy Graph',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            var options = {
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    series: []
                },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [i, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });

    });
```

But i want it dynamically careated when i pass my json data.
json data is

```
json is {"09/02/2014 15:36:25":[33.82,33.42,40.83],"08/11/2014 16:25:15":[36.6,33.42,40.45],"07/30/2014 08:43:57":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"08/12/2014 22:00:52":[77.99,74.1,80.12],"08/12/2014 21:19:48":[56.91,63.23,52.42],"07/23/2014 13:37:46":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"08/11/2014 17:35:21":[40.9,43.83,38.34]}
```

I Want date in x-axis (ex: 09/02/2014 15:36:25 )  and three value in y axis ex: (33.82,33.42,40.83) for three lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert your format to format supported by Highcharts, for example:

```
var data = {
    "09/02/2014 15:36:25": [33.82, 33.42, 40.83],
        "08/11/2014 16:25:15": [36.6, 33.42, 40.45],
        "07/30/2014 08:43:57": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "08/12/2014 22:00:52": [77.99, 74.1, 80.12],
        "08/12/2014 21:19:48": [56.91, 63.23, 52.42],
        "07/23/2014 13:37:46": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "08/11/2014 17:35:21": [40.9, 43.83, 38.34]
};

var series = [{
    name: 'some name 1',
    data: []
}, {
    name: 'some name 2',
    data: []
}, {
    name: 'some name 3',
    data: []
}],
    categories = [];


for(var category in data) {
    var points = data[category];
    categories.push(category);
    for(var i in points) {
         series[i].data.push(points[i]);  
    }
}

var i = 7.0;
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Search Relevancy Graph',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: series
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywr3L/22/